# Why should I not always pass a Django request context in a view?

Tags: django

According to the [relevant Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), a request context offers more than a normal context in that it merges request data into the context.

It is hence necessary for views that perform form submission in Django.

However, I am wondering why one cannot just always pass a request context for every view. After all, a request context offers more than a normal context.

Why not create a helper function called, say, `render()` that automatically passes a request context? Is there a performance disadvantage?

Comment: `django.shortcuts.render` is an easy way to use `RequestContext`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a performance disadvantage. It should be faster to render a template with an small context than with big context (i.e. the request context).

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your answer?